# Could not resolve project :url_launcher_macos

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I create new app in flutter and it's work when I run it, but when I add shared_preferences package, I got this error when I run it

> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':url_launcher:compileDebugAidl'.
>   Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':url_launcher:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve project :url_launcher_macos.
>        Required by:
>            project :url_launcher
>   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :url_launcher_macos:
>             - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and i have fixed this with running following command:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

If this is not working then please try the following:

`flutter channel stable` then run the commands
`flutter clean` and `flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Neither package is compatible with mac

Comment: Could you provide more details? eg post a page where it states that the packages are compatible with mac os?

Answer (score 0):

> This worked for me

**NOTE:- CLOSE THE FLUTTER PROJECT**

1. Go to Flutter sdk path
2. Enable the view hidden files in Mac by using CTRL + SHIFT + .
3. Go to .pub-cache
4. Go to hosted
5. Go to pub.dartlang.org
6. delete this folder `url_launcher_macos`
7. Open the project and run app